# Custom element selector - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to javascript and i am making a script and i'm using `document.getElementById` and `document.getElementsByClassName` alot and i need to keep typing it every time plus it takes up so much lines.

So i am trying to make my own custom element selector but i can't get it to work and was hoping me someone could help me workout why it does not work. Or if there would be a better way to make a custom element selector.

What i tried:

```js
const getElement = (el) => { return [...document.querySelectorAll(el)] };

let divWithClass = getElement('my-class');
console.log('div with class', divWithClass[0].innerText);

let divWithId = getElement('my-id');
console.log('div with id', divWithId.innerText);
```

```html
<div class='my-class'>My div with class</div>
<div id='my-id'>My div with id</div>
```

Comment: Your selectors are incorrect. `my-class` selects elements like `<my-class>`, not elements like `<div class='my-class'>`. You need `.my-class`.

Comment: Your selectors are incorrect. They should be `getElement('.my-class')` and `getElement('#my-id')` respectively (note the starting `.` and `#`)

Comment: Also, a method in the singular which returns an array seems like a bad choice. Perhaps consider 2 methods `getElement` which returns a single element and `getElements` which returns an array

Comment: Also note that `getElement` always returns an array. So even if you expect only one element (`getElement('#my-id')`) you need to access it apropriately: `divWithId[0].innerText`

Comment: Basically, "better" is in the eye of the beholder. I happen to think `querySelector`/`querySelectorAll` is pretty good already. But I know CSS selectors pretty well, and that's what it uses. And I can already use `forEach` on the result, and `Array.from` is there (or spread syntax) if I need to use `map` or another array-specific function.

Comment: ...and if you work with an IDE with auto-completion, then you won't have to type it out over and over.

Comment: If an answer helped you, then please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3):

You almost had it

```js
const getElement = (el) => [...document.querySelectorAll(el)];

let divWithClass = getElement('.my-class');
console.log('div with class', divWithClass[0].innerText);

let divWithId = getElement('#my-id');
console.log('div with id', divWithId[0].innerText);
```

```html
<div class='my-class'>My div with class</div>
<div id='my-id'>My div with id</div>
```